# Which if any philosophers might be considered affiliated with Wittgenstein's school of thought or have expressed similar views?

Tags: reference-request, wittgenstein

Are there any philosophers who might be considered affiliated or belonging to the same turn or school, or perhaps hold the same kind of views, as Wittgenstein?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the challenges you encountered trying to read Wittgenstein?

Comment: I share your difficulty in understanding Wittgenstein's writings, and if assume correctly, your unfavorable opinion of his style. There are a number of very short intro's to W, that are much more explicit. Kripke comments on W in a favorable style, but that's another level deeper.

Comment: I don't mean for this to expand into a discussion about why I find Wittgenstein's writing murky by design, but compare for example the introduction of the Tractatus by Russel and the main text of the Tractatus. Just compare the amount of different interpretations of what Wittgenstein says in his philosophy and the number of interpretations what Russel says in his philosophy (are there even debates about what Russel actually thought?).

Comment: Is there any chance I might be able to persuade you to reframe the question line here? My suggestion might be: "what are some strategies and/or secondary literature to make wittgenstein approachable?" (The basic suggestion is to avoid an open-ended question.)

Comment: Well, the thing is I'm not looking for secondary litterature about what Wittgenstein might have thought. I've already found good books about this. The thing is, I don't want to read philosophers whose philosophy is up for interpretation. If people need to have long discussions about what a person thought about a certain matter, then that philosopher probably didn't know him-/herself. Why read a whole book regarding if Wittgenstein held position x or y when he just could have written the answer himself?

Comment: I am concerned that this really isn't entirely appropriate as currently formulated. Asking for "alternatives" to a philosopher is a bit too open-ended, and perhaps even somewhat nonsensical: there is no substitute for reading a book or author.

Comment: Seriously, could the moderators at SE Philosophy stop with their extremely aggressive and highly subjective closing of threads? If this isn't within the boundaries of what is allowed, I don't know what is (bear in mind that the question has received two upvotes and three answers; obviously, the community doesn't deem it as either nonsensical or open-ended. I am interested in exactly the questions that Wittgenstein ralks about but I can't stand his unclear style. I would like to know who I should read instead who is close to him. I think this is extremely straight-forward.

Comment: Please note that closure is not intended as punishment and does not have to be permanent. Your question may be straightforward but is not particularly constructive. The issue is what I raised above -- there is no meaningful "alternative" to actually reading a specific writer or work. Again my suggestion (as made by several answers below, I note) is to reframe this to ask for help with whatever particular challenges you might be encountering with the work.

Comment: @Joseph Voted to reopen - I agree with Speldosa. The closing policy - as I have indicated elsewhere - is putting people off.

Comment: @Chuck I am pretty sensitive to this, and certainly am not trying to discourage well-meaning participation. I have offered suggestions as to reformulations, but this is just really problematic to me as written. Note there is [a related meta discussion about the question](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/310/why-was-my-question-on-alternatives-to-wittgenstein-closed) which you may wish to contribute to

Comment: I think the question is way too broad to be useful (even after the edit).  If you were to focus on a specific topic from _Tractatus_ and/or _PI_ and ask something like, "I want to read more about `X`, which I know Wittgenstein covers.  But I find his writing style too hard going.  Does any other philosopher cover `X` in a more readable way?"  As it is, the "question" sounds more like a rant about Wittgenstein's writing-style than a real query about any particular philosophical topic.

Comment: @Joseph If I were to ask: 'I find Deleuze impenetrable; is there anyone affiliated to his school of thought that has expressed similar views, or is widely considered to have held similar views, that I could read in order to get a handle on Deleuze's ideas?' Surely that's an acceptable question - it asks for historical context and scholarly help, two categories philstack ought to accommodate. I think you guys are getting put off by the rant in the beginning, but it really has nothing to do with the actual question. I maintain my position.

Comment: @Chuck that is an interesting point. Now regardless of the thinker I would still have an issue with the idea that there is an "alternative" to a philosopher, that could give you the same material "more simply" -- besides secondary literature on the thinker in question... I would definitely reconsider my close-vote here given a more reasonably-scoped, less open-ended formulation. Now, asking after other thinkers holding "similar" views or "affiliated" with a given turn or school -- this would be completlely satisfactory to me.

Comment: @Chuck I think your message may have been cut short?

Comment: @Joseph Probably a mistaken click. By the way I just noticed that what we've been calling a 'rant' is Speldosa saying 'I am not going to rant'

Comment: @Joseph I took the liberty of editing the question in order to get it re-opened. If you think this is not in line with the spirit of the original question I will retract my edits.

Comment: @Chuck: There's a certain Magritte quality to "I am not going to rant".  But with your edit, I voted to reopen.  I still think the question is marginal and I'd really like the OP to clarify what they they intended to ask.

Comment: Thanks, @Chuck. I want to note here that I still find this somewhat problematic; despite the very good reformulation you have performed the way the question is structured still asks for an "alternative" (instead of asking for help addressing particular challenges, or of asking for quality secondary literature that could help, or asking for help in general.)

Comment: That said, I am voting to reopen at this time because your edit is a vast improvement, and at least partially displaces the problem I am outlining above. I would like to confirm with Speldosa that we haven't altered her intent here too fundamentally.

Comment: The edit is fine. I still hold that I don't want to read Wittgenstein since I'm suspicious of philosophers who write in a style that is too much open for interpretation (compare the amount of interpretation between for example Wittgensteins' texts and Frege or Russel) and where the secondary litterature focuses on what that philosopher thought rather than on what is correct. Anyhow, the edit will still generate the answers that I'm after and that's the important part for me.

Comment: I have tried to trim down and focus the question a bit around the reframed concern. Please feel free to develop this further.

Comment: I can't see much difference between early Wittgenstein and Russell, except for style issues. The logical positivists were also influenced by the idea of a formal language. Later Wittgenstein I haven't read.

Answer (score 5):

Even though his style is rather simple and direct, Wittgenstein is not someone whose writing you can just pick up and 'dive into.' I'd recommend familiarizing yourself with a lot of context before even beginning to read - not only as far as the content is concerned but also as far as the dialectical form. The Investigations for instance make little sense unless you take care to separate the three interlocutors in the text - separated by single, double or no quotation marks. Similarly, you need to be aware of the separate, stand-alone arguments that litter the Tractatus - that is the only way to give the text structure (the numbering of the propositions creates the illusion of a single strain of thought, pursued to completion, but that's not at all how one should read the Tractatus (if, that is, one wants to avoid frustration).) So, in summary, read a lot of exegeses and/or introductory essays (e.g. Anscombe or Potter for the Tractatus, the Routledge volume for the Investigations etc.) before engaging with the texts, make sure you are familiar with the structure and, finally, a lot of historical context won't do any harm, although that is advice true of any text, philosophical or otherwise.

Now on the other hand, to answer your actual question, are there any other philosophers who write more clearly on the issues Wittgenstein himself was concerned with? I don't know - clarity is certainly a matter of taste. I for one think Wittgenstein is by far the clearest philosopher I have ever read and find a lot of the analytic philosophers that succeeded him and who wrote in the name of 'clarity and rigour' much harder to penetrate. I will suppose that you are interested in (what is now labelled) the philosophy of language. The problem is no-one has written like Wittgenstein or about the things Wittgenstein wrote about in much the same way - and I am guessing you are not after scholarly appraisals or purely exegetical works. The only contemporary philosopher I would recommend in that vein is Richard Rorty - he is a great writer and very lucid and, in my opinion, holds ideas that Wittgenstein would surely have sympathized with.

Comment: "The Investigations for instance make little sense unless you take care to separate the three interlocutors in the text - separated by single, double or no quotation marks." - Does Wittgenstein mention anywhere that he uses this form? Otherwise, I would say that he's making it more confusing than it has to be. This is a great example of where he is unclear. i'll check out Richard Rorty though. Thanks!

Comment: @Speldosa Well he doesn't mention it explicitly anywhere but you can tell that the text is written in a discursive style. Look, I think you are confusing lack of clarity with lack of context. Witt himself is certainly culpable for not giving enough context to his writing, e.g. giving a long introduction where he describes his methods and purpose. But it's not that this context does not exist. It certainly does. A little historical background  on both the text itself and Wittgenstein's views will give you the context to understand what and how the Investigations are supposed to be read (cont.)

Comment: And once you have that context I'm sure you'll find that he is very clear (and incredibly lucid.) The text is very approachable if you know that you are not supposed to read a doctrine into it or a single unified strand of thought (i.e. an uber-argument.) The Investigations are a collection of elucidations. The movements in it should be seen as Witt's attempt to cure people of the philosophical impulse (i.e. the impulse to philosophize) and NOT of trying to solve philosophical problems.He does so by deconstructing many paradigmatic philosoph situations. PI128: There are no theses in philosophy

Answer (score 3):

As far as contemporaries of Wittgenstein, who are usually thought to be in the ordinary-language school, I'd suggest Ryle, Strawson, and Hare. Austin and Searle began to move away from "meaning as use" philosophy, but are considered to be affiliated with Witt (but I do remember reading that Austin called Wittgenstein, "a charlatan").

Although Grice, Quine, Davidson, and Kirpke are not of the same school as W., they are often regarded as the offspring of the Ordinary Language School--though, perhaps, antagonistic offspring.

As Chuck mentioned above, Richard Rorty would also perhaps be considered of the same "turn" as Witt. Kuhn is also a Wittgensteinian of sorts (and Rorty claimed that Kuhn was one of the great heroes of his *Philosophy and the Mirror of Nature*). And, with Kuhn, you might want to look at Feyerabend (who was also greatly influenced by Witt).

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, I don't know of any philosophers who write with more clarity than Wittgenstein.  The *Philosophical Investigations* are a serious of thought experiments which, unlike most philosophical texts, do not rely on extensive knowledge of previous philosophers.

Is there something particular you are having trouble understanding? I have yet to find a section of the *PI* that did not yield to a slow, patient reading.  And I think that Wittgenstein's style in the *PI* is directly tied to the content; he is attempting to say obliquely that which cannot be said any other way.

Perhaps you could post a specific question about some passage that is confusing you?

As for the *Tractatus*, it is much more compressed; however, there is a large secondary literature explicating the arguments and filling in the gaps.

Comment: I would consider 'oblique' (what you said) and 'obscurantist' (from the wikipedia [article on obscurantism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obscurantism#Wittgenstein) to be somewhat the same as 'not clear'. Yes, W uses non-technical language, but that's quite different from 'clear'. Can you elaborate on how you think W is more clear than say Russell or ..(I'm trying to think of someone relevant) Kripke?

Comment: I suppose it is a matter of personal judgment, but I find Wittgenstein's thought experiments very easy to follow and engage with.  I do not think they are intentionally obscure; rather, they are *necessarily* oblique, as they are an attempt to *not* pass over in silence that which we cannot say-- they must approach their subject indirectly, and point to things that cannot be explicitly formulated.  As for Russell: he can be quite clear in his more popular works; on the other hand, I spent a couple years struggling with the *Principia Mathematica* and only managed a hundred pages or so.

Answer (score 1):

In french there is an excellent book by **Pierre Hadot** (first to introduce Wittgenstein in France) about the tractacus it's called **"Wittgenstein et les limites du langage"**. It explores what is called "mystic" by wittgenstein.  I don't know if the book has been translated.

Comment: It has not yet been translated into English, sadly. Hadot is gradually being translated more often, though; I hope that this one will arrive before too long.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know french and I don't want to read secondary litterature about Wittgenstein :)

Comment: @Speldosa I think Pierre Hadot had this humility that is the subject of many philosophy but that is shared by few philosopher. A lot of its litterature might look like secondary litterature (comments of others) if you look at the titles but it more than that. I would even say he had a fundamental influence on other important french philosopher (Foucault is a noticable exemple). He was not running after something "new" (i.e. determined by what exists) but after something truly deep inside his soul and that of humanity.